# MySQL date shows as 0000-00-00 windows application .net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

My connection string to the DB has the `Allow Zero Datetime=True;` The whole program works perfectly, the only problem is that Date does not.

I tested the same program with an access DB and it works flawlessly. This issue only happens on MySQL DB that is necessary for my project.

This is an insert statement that I have only my DB under a history table

```
SqlVentaCasas = "INSERT INTO VentaCasasHistory (ID, Direccion, Estatus, Precio, " & _
                            "NumeroDias, FechaHoy, Agente, Compania, Unidad, Ciudad ) VALUES ('" & _
                            AddIDCasas2 & "','" & AddDireccionCasas2 & "','" & AddEstatusCasas2 & "'," & AddPrecioCasas2 & ", " & NumeroDiasCasas2 & " ,'" & _
                            Date.Today & "','" & AgenteNameCasas2 & "','" & AgenteCompaniaCasas2 & "', '" & AddUnidadCasas2 & "', '" & AddCiudadCasas2 & "' );"
```

The date shows as 0000-00-00 in my .net windows application. How can I resolve it?

Comment: "Date does not [work]" means what, exactly? Are you seeing 0000-00-00 dates in the database via that insert statement? Are you getting those back from queries (which causes DateTime to throw an exception)?

Comment: MySQL table schema? What is `Date.Today`? Need more information...

Comment: @siride the program enters a day such as today "ex: Sep, 15, 2012 on the database but when i enter that date it is saved on the database as 0000-00-00 instead of 2012-09-15

Comment: @j.w.r the statement above is from windows application .net and Date.Today should enter today's date on the Database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `Date.Today` to `Date.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`. I believe the default date format is `MM/dd/yyyy` for `Date.Today` without any format string which MySQL may not like in this instance.

Comment: What happens is that it performs a division operation, and since the denominator (the year) is always bigger than the numerators, the result will be integer 0.